# Font Detection (TTF or WOFF) via CSS Media Queries

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, media-queries

I was wondering if CSS Media Queries can be used to detect whether a device can load a particular font format (TTF or WOFF, not just any @Font-Face). I'm not looking to check for screen size and then load a particular font based on the screen size. Thank you for any help, suggestions, a better way to word this to continue my searches.

Update: I was told that this is not an option:
{font: 60px/68px 'ArnoProBoldTTF', 'ArnoProBoldWoff';letter-spacing: 0;}

Where it tries to load the first font and then if it cannot, goes to the 2nd one.

Comment: Why is this required? Browsers, at least desktop browsers, only download the necessary (eot/woff/ttf/svg) font file, not all of them.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with [media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/). You must use a javascript workaround to find out that the font is available (and loaded).

Just curious, for what reason do you need this? There could be a better way to achieve your goal without requiring this type of detection.
If you just want to load specific embedded font across all devices and browsers, there is a simple solution. I'll update my answer if necessary.

Comment: I was asked if it was possible, I didn't think it was so I continued to search. I knew you could do it in javascript.